# For all $M \gt 0$ there exists $z \in G$ such that $|z|^3+z+\overline{z} = M$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to show that if $G$ is an open, unbounded, connected set and if $0 \in G$ then for every $M \gt 0$ there exists $z \in G$ such that $|z|^3+z+\overline{z} = M$. Here's what I did and I think it's right but looking for confirmation.

Define $f(z)=|z|^3+z+\overline{z}$ continuous in $\mathbb{C}$ with real values. $f(0)=0$.

Let $M \gt 0$

Since $G$ is unbounded there is some $w \in G$ such that $|w| = R \gt M$ and then $f(w) = |w|^3 + w + \overline{w} = R^3+2Rew \gt R^3-2R \gt R \gt M$ (because $R$ is as large as we want)

Then since $f$ is real valued and continuous in $G$ and we found $f(0)\lt M \lt f(w)$ there must be $z \in G$ with $f(z)=M$

Is this right?

Comment: You need to use the fact that $G$ is connected. Since $G$ is connected, and $f$ is continuous, $f(G)$ is a connected subset of the real line, so it is an interval. In particular, $f(G)$ contains $f(0)$ and $f(w)$ so it will contain all the intermediate values.